# Android Service and UI Thread

Tags: android, service, ui-thread

I have a Service running in my app..

This Service has an object for sending message to the server and a function to get that object and use it.

The object is initialized from the Service and yet when the UI gets this objects and use it - it looks like it uses it on the UI Thread..

Is this correct ? Is there a way i can make my object always run from the Service Thread ?

```
public class ServerMessagesManager extends Service {
    private ServerMessagesReceiver serverMessageReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.serverMessageReceiver = new ServerMessagesReceiver(app);
    }

    public ServerMessagesReceiver getServerMessagesReceiver()
    {
        return serverMessageReceiver;
    }
}
```

Comment: a service runs on the ui thread. take a look at intentservice for services that run a part of the process on a separated thread

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `IntentService` instead of `Service`. If you do network calls in a `Service`, the UI will stuck. Therefore, use an `IntentService` since it uses a separate `Thread`.

And you do not know when a server message will retrieve the data. A `NullPointerException` could be thrown if objects are accessed as long as network calls are still in progress. Use `BroadcastReceiver`s to fire an `Intent` whenever a server responds.

Answer (score 5):

As far I know, Android service run on UI thread. If you want to make an asynchronous job, you should use `Intent Service` 
See: 
[What is the difference between an IntentService and a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771323/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intent-service-and-a-service)

Here is an [Intent service example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) you can try.