# ANR with code running on separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

**Background:**

This app is a simple Wifi manager, collecting/scanning and displaying results in a list view. Since this scan scans on a interval, I have created a thread and set a Thread.sleep(interval) between scans, so after processing is done, it sleeps for X milliseconds.

I have made a few "changes"/updates to my code, now my app goes into a ANR state with an debugger message `"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3`

**Full Error:**

```
07-01 10:14:16.772 10027-10034/com.cynetstudios.wifimanager I/art: Thread[2,tid=10034,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa9007000,peer=0x12d1a0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
07-01 10:14:17.101 10027-10034/com.cynetstudios.wifimanager I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Problem:

**Before Permissions added:**

In the `onCreate()` of main, I had my code to initiate my scan loop and start outputting data, this worked and was outputting data as expected.

**Thread Code:**

```
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!bStopThread) {
                ThreadCounter++;

                if (bSafe) {
                    initWiFiArrays(); //Scans and inserts data into lists
                    CreateSetAdapter(); //Converts lists into adapter, and sets adapter to ExpandableListView
                    threadRefresh.setText("# Refreshed Times : " + String.valueOf(ThreadCounter));
                    writeResultsToFile(); //Write results to file
                } else
                    stopScan();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(scanInterval);
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

**After Permissions added:**

After doing some research, I discovered that I should remove this `Initiate scan` method from onCreate since it blocks any thread calls, I added it to onStart and added a method `RunOnUITHD(Runnable r)` which will only access UI to update with essential code.

**New Thread Code:**

```
     t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!bStopThread) {
                ThreadCounter++;

                if (bSafe) {
                    initWiFiArrays();
                    CreateSetAdapter();
                    RunOnUITHD(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            threadRefresh.setText("# Refreshed Times : " + String.valueOf(ThreadCounter));
                        }
                    });
                    writeResultsToFile();
                } else
                    stopScan();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(scanInterval);
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Handler is defined by : `handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());`

**RunOnUITHD**

```
private void RunOnUITHD(Runnable runnable) {
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

I am still getting ANR ([latest ANR Traces](http://pastebin.com/JZh74T8s)) and I am out of idea's, I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

I logged every part of the main thread code, it is running as expected, looping and sleeping, but UI is not updating...

Adding Logging code to the `new Runnable()` I notice the following:

adding a breakpoint to ThreadCounter of e.g. `ThreadCounter==11` should result in 10 "Updaing Thread..." and "Finished update..." loops as seen from code below.

```
RunOnUITHD(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        logm("POST HANDLER: updating Thread Refresh Text");
        threadRefresh.setText("# Refreshed Times : " + String.valueOf(ThreadCounter));
        logm("POST HANDLER: Finished update Thread Refresh Text");
    }
});
```

Instead I only note 4 loops that are shown in log.

Running further tests, `ThreadCounter==3`, loops logged = 1, allfurther tests results in 1 logged loop of Updating setText.

Since this thread is initiated via a custom method of `checkPermissions()` in my `@Override onStart()`, I show a toast message, followed by the checkPermissions

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(main.this, "Starting Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    logm("checking permissions in 'onStart'");
    checkPermissions();
}
```

thoughout these tests, the Toast Message shows (does not disappear) and the setText updates on 1 loop, meaning the `threadRefresh` TextView contains the following text : "# Refreshed Times : 1"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I did not have a deadlock, it was due to a poor choice in `Intents`.

**Cause:**

What I used was an `Intent`. This created a service which created a `PendingIntent` (for the click on notifcation to reopen app), this locked my UI thread. SO nothing in my code above affect/caused the problem!

**How I solved this:**

Use logs. Not Custom defined logs, just simple `Log.i()`

I logged each part of my code:

1. Starting off at high level, and working down to a possible cause.
2. If that doesn't work/produce results, see if you have any other classes, in my case a ServiceClass, log that.

This is where I found my code did not execute further, so back tracing to the calling code, I discovered that I used an Intent which waits for the intent to finish before moving on, thus causing my code to hang.

**Solution:**

should have used is one of 2 types of Intents meant for services.

- [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
- [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

These are frequently asked and well documented objects. There are many questions on StackOverflow regarding the difference between these 2 intent types, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771323/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intentservice-and-a-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice?lq=1) are 2 highly ranked questions, and a little [UI and service Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702922/android-service-and-ui-thread?lq=1)

I will be using a IntentService.

Hope this helps!