# How sticky service runs when application is not alive?

Tags: android

I have found that Service is run in Main Thread i.e. UI Thread in Android whereas Intent Service runs in a new worker thread(Reference link: [What is the difference between an IntentService and a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771323/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intentservice-and-a-service)). My question is if I killed the application then the main thread of that app should be closed. Then how a sticky service runs in background?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky